# Combining logical functions in R

Tags: r

I'm running several tests for a given object `x`. For a given test (being a test a function that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` when applied to an object) it is quite easy, as you can do `lapply(x, test)`. For example:

```
# This would return TRUE
lapply('a', is.character)
```

However, I would like to create a function `pass_tests`, which would be able to combine multiple tests, i.e. that it could run something like this:

```
pass_tests('a', is.character | is.numeric)
```

Therefore, it should combine multiple functions given in an argument of the function, combining its result when testing an object `x`. In this case, it would return whether `'a'` is character OR numeric, which would be `TRUE`. The following line should return `FALSE`:

```
pass_tests('a', is.character & is.numeric)
```

The idea is that it could be flexible for different combinations , e.g.:

```
pass_tests(x, test1 & (test2 | test3))
```

Any idea if functions can be logically combined this way?

Comment: Something like this? `f1 = function(x,a,b) {a(x) & b(x)};
f2 = function(x,a,b) {a(x) | b(x)};
f1("a", is.numeric, is.character);
f2("a", is.numeric, is.character)`

Comment: Yes, that would solve the examples. I was wondering though if a unique function could contemplate multiple combinations (taking into account that there could be multiple tests).

Comment: Every test could be a function that returns TRUE/FALSE and then you can combine those in one function. The example above assumes one input and 2 tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to use the pipes

```
library(magrittr) # or dplyr
"a" %>% {is.character(.) & is.numeric(.)} 
#FALSE
"a" %>% {is.character(.) | is.numeric(.)} 
#TRUE

1 %>% {is.finite(.) & (is.character(.) | is.numeric(.))} 
#TRUE
```

Edit: used in a function with string

```
pass_test <- function(x, expr) {

  x %>% {eval(parse(text = expr))}
}

pass_test(1, "is.finite(.) & (is.character(.) | is.numeric(.))")
#TRUE
```

The argument `expr` can be a string or an expression as in `expression(is.finite(.) & (is.character(.) | is.numeric(.)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it by creating infix operators.

```
`%and%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  function(...) lhs(...) & rhs(...)
}

`%or%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  function(...) lhs(...) | rhs(...)
}


(is.character %and% is.numeric)('a')
#> [1] FALSE

(is.character %or% is.numeric)('a')
#> [1] TRUE
```

These can be chained together. However, it will not have the normal AND/OR precedence. It will be evaluated left-to-right.

```
(is.double %and% is.numeric %and% is.finite)(12)
#> [1] TRUE
```